Unable to Withdraw from Staking Account Due to Withdraw Authority Issue
I started staking with Solana using the Phantom Wallet. When staking is initiated through the Phantom Wallet, no private key is generated for the staking account itself. However, due to some glitch, the withdraw authority of the staking account has been set to the staking account address itself. As a result, I am unable to withdraw funds from the wallet.
Is it possible to reset the withdraw authority from the staking account address (which has no private key) back to my original account using the CLI? Any guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

maybe a duplicity to https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/14107/change-stake-account-withdraw-auth-where-the-auth-is-the-account-address-it-self ?
