change stake account withdraw auth where the auth is the account address it self
for development purposes i did the following:

created stake account
change its withdraw auth to the account address
now i am trying to figure how i can change the withdraw auth back to wallet owner of this account.

would love to hear insights.
the account: https://solscan.io/account/F6JmyC5EFtHnt7yvAtzSiSUdEPpU7tCqbnhHsddUBgdj
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
i know that if i had the account keypair i could easily sign on its behalf, but i dont.
so i wonder what the case here, as the wallet who created the account who still the "owner" of this account or its "lost" account.
the creator of this account is JPQmr9p2RF3X5TuBXxn6AGcEfcsHp4ehcmzE5Ys7pZD
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/GP8ZpasQ.png

I believe there is no way to change the account into ownership of the "owner" when the withdraw authority keypair is lost (or does not exist).
It's the withdrawer who has got all permissions to handle the stake account.
(maybe it's a similar situation to this question and some glitch is in play? Unable to Withdraw from Staking Account Due to Withdraw Authority Issue)
